# How can I redirect to a jsp page from my controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I did some searching prior to this and cannot find anything that fits my question. I have a Sprint Boot app with an initial page that every time a user goes to the index.jsp adds a number to a counter of visitors. They can go to the counter jsp will display the current count and a "Test Another Visit" link. There is another counter2.jsp page that if a user visits, it gives the current count plus one additional visit added to it. A "reset" link on each page should reset the counter to 0 and return the user to /counter or /counter two based on the page they clicked the reset button.

I have the following Rest Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping("/reset")
    public String reset(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        String redirectUrl = "";
        if(request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/counter")) {
            session.setAttribute("current", 0);
            redirectUrl = "redirect:/counter";
        } else if (request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("/counter2")) {
            session.setAttribute("current", 0);
            redirectUrl = "redirect:/counter2";
        }
        return redirectUrl;
    }
```

Which gives me this error:
[image: Image of the error]

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? I am new to Spring.

Thank you,

I apologize in advance if I somehow 'asked" my question wrong, I know some people seem to get upset about that.

Also, this is not for an assignment, just personal practice.

Comment: You can use ModelAndView to redirect in jsp page

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.